# Spring 4.2 ApplicationContext NoClassDefFound Error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have the following code.

```
// MessagePrinter.java
public class MessagePrinter {
    private String message;
    public MessagePrinter(String input){
        message = input;
    }
}

// ApplicationConfig.java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessagePrinter getMessagePrinter(){
         return new MessagePrinter("Bean");
    }
}

// Application.java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    }
}
```

The error I get when I run Application in Eclipse is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. I am in the process of migrating from cplusplus to java and brand new to the spring framework. All the documentation I read online tells me that this code should work fine. My goal is to extract the MessagePrinter class from the ApplicationContext which is created in main. However, the first statement itself causes the code to crash. Any clues? I am an absolute Java noob. So feel free to point out the most obvious.

I am using Spring 4.2.7

The actual error message from Eclipse is given below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:159)
at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.<init>(GenericApplicationContext.java:102)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:60)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:82)
at hello.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 5 more
```

Comment: have you added the requisite spring related jars in classpath?

Comment: I have added the spring 4.2.7 jars as external jars in the build path for the eclipse project properties. Is this what you mean? I have not copied the jars into the local folder.

Comment: I don't know which all spring-jars are you using. `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` resides in spring-context jar.

Comment: Yeah, I have the spring-context, spring-core and spring-beans added as external jars. They appear in the Referenced Libraries of my Java project in Eclipse. The code builds fine. This is a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing commons-logging.jar in your classpath. This jar is required by spring-core.

If your project is a maven project add this to your pom.xml in dependencies section

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <!-- change version as applicable -->
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can manually add the jars in Eclipse. Download jars from

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2

Comment: OK, I created the project using a wizard in Eclipse. Suspect its not a maven project (i don't know what maven is). I will try to manually add the jar. Was there any logical way from the error to figure out the missing jar?

Comment: Your question is a valid one, and this did annoy me, when I started out with java (not that I am expert now). But in general, as one gets familiar with tools around java, they start using tools like Maven/Gradle to setup project and resolve dependencies. Maven would have automatically downloaded commons-logging and add it to classpath. Don't worry this initial struggle will help you in the long run. I blame the tutorial which you were following (if it did not mention adding required jars too). For now add jars manually and then try again. :)

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up. But yes, I did get it working by adding a few more external jars. commons-logging was definitely needed but it did not solve the problem entirely. I did have to add a few more but it did work eventually. This pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.